# How to get ControlTemplate from ResourceDictionary?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a resource dictionary file in my app (Themes\MyDictionary). There is a control template with the x:Key property. How to get it in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a new ResourceDictionary object.

2) Set the ResourceDictionary.Source property pointing to the XAML file with the Page build action.

3) Get template by string key.

```
static object GetDefaultToolTipTemplate() {

    // 1)                                             
    ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary() { 

        // 2) 
        Source = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Themes/ToolTip.xaml", UriKind.Absolute) 
    };

    // 3)
    ControlTemplate template = (ControlTemplate)rd["DefaultStyleForTooltipInControlTooltipOwner"];

    return template;
}
```